# laravel use mssql stored procedure for google charts

Tags: sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures

Now  i got all chart. 
but i need just a `id=1-10` .
please help me

model

```
public function Overall_byDepartment()
{
    $sQuery  = "EXEC  [dbo].[WebReport_Overall_byDepartment]" ;
    $aRawResults = DB::connection($this->connection)->select($sQuery);
    return $aRawResults; 
}
```

Comment: There are few things, that aren't clear in your question:
1. What are you trying to do? 2. What's not working? 3. What result do you expect.
People will be able to help you, once they could understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
public function index(Request $request) 
{
    $aData= $this->oChartManager->Overall_byDepartment();
    $this->aData['sReportName'] = 'dashboard';
    $this->oChartManager->setReportName('dashboard');
    $this->aData['aData']= $aData ;

    $result[] = ['department_name','oascore','level0_score' ];
    foreach ($aData as $value)  {
        $value = [(string)$value->department_name,
            (float)$value->oascore,
            (float)$value->level0_score,
        ];      

        array_push($result, $value);

    return view('reports.template')->with('aData',json_encode($result));
}
```